# Boost::Signals encapsulation over network

Tags: c++, boost, ipc, distributed-computing

I am currently involved in the development of a software using distributed computing to detect different events.

*The current approach is* : a dozen of threads are running simultaneously on different (physical) computers. Each event is assigned a number ; and every thread broadcasts its detected events to the other and filters the relevant events from the incoming stream.

I feel very bad about that, because it looks awful, is hard to maintain and could lead to performance issues when the system will be upgraded.

So I am looking for a flexible and elegant way to handle this IPC, and I think Boost::Signals seems a good candidate ; but I never used it, and I would like to know whether it is possible to provide encapsulation for network communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know any solution that will do that, other then Open MPI, if I had to do that, I would first use [Google's Protocol Buffer](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) as my message container.  With it, I could just create an abstract base message with stuff like source, dest, type, id, etc.  Then, I would use [Boost ASIO](http://boost-sandbox.sourceforge.net/boost_1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) to distribute those across the network, or over a Named PIPE/loopback for local messages.  Maybe, in each physical computer, a dedicated process could be running just for distribution.  Each thread registers with it which types of messages it is interested in, and what its named pipe is called.  This process would know the IP of all the other services.

Answer (score 0):

If you need IPC over the network then boost::signals won't help you, at least not entirely by itself.

You could try using [Open MPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer ; yet Open MPI seems quite big for my problem. 
Maybe I can broaden my question : do you know any (open source) generic library to wrap thread communication over different network protocols ?

Comment: No I don't, but I'll add another answer with another suggestion.